# I want to merge multiple select queries i.e. column enhancement to be one table in access 2007. what could be possible solution?

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

These are the separate queres I wrote which work fine separately. Help me to merge it

```
SELECT sum(Total) as RoomRevenue,
       sum(ExtraCharges) AS Extra, 
       sum(Discount) AS DiscountGiven, 
       sum(Tax) AS TaxCollection, 
       sum(GrandTotal) AS TotalCollection, 
       regDate
FROM tblRegistration 
GROUP BY regDate;

SELECT Count(*) AS OcuppiedRooms, 
       regDate 
FROM tblRegistration
WHERE (((tblRegistration.[CheckInDate])<=[regDate]) 
  AND ((tblRegistration.[CheckOutDate])>=[regDate])) 
GROUP BY tblRegistration.regDate;

SELECT Sum(ExtraCharges) AS TheatreTickets, 
       regDate
FROM tblRegistration 
WHERE ExtraChargesType = 'Tickets' 
GROUP BY tblRegistration.regDate;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have access handy, but I'll give it a shot "free hand" and see how it goes :)
Since Access does not (afaik) have `CASE`, the trick would seem to be to use `IIF`;

```sql
SELECT SUM(Total) as RoomRevenue,
       SUM(ExtraCharges) AS Extra, 
       SUM(Discount) AS DiscountGiven, 
       SUM(Tax) AS TaxCollection, 
       SUM(GrandTotal) AS TotalCollection, 
       SUM(IIF(ExtraChargesType = 'Tickets', ExtraCharges, 0)) AS TheatreTickets,
       SUM(IIF([CheckInDate])<=[regDate] AND [CheckOutDate])>=[regDate], 1, 0)) AS OcuppiedRooms
       regDate
FROM tblRegistration 
GROUP BY regDate;
```